# Where is the line between unit and integration test (on example)?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have a problem in understanding where is (or should be) a line between those two kind of tests. So, I have a dummy example: A simple tic-tac-toe game. The game has its own board (3x3) with 9 cells. Dependencies are obvious: **Game <- Board <- Cell**.

Quick description: Every time user click *"New Game"*, the new **Game** is created (by GameFactory) and **Board** needs to be cleared/reset. In the entire lifetime of GameFactory there there is single object of Board. Reset the Board means to create brand new **Cell** objects. Here is the code:

**GameFactory:** (as you can see I created Board once, so I need to reset it in Game constructor):

```
public class GameFactory : IGameFactory
{
    private readonly IBoard board;
    public GameFactory(IBoard board)
    {
        this.board = board;
    }
    public IGame Create()
    {
        return new Game(board);
    }
}
```

**Cell and CellFactory**

```
public interface ICell
{
    int PlayerId { get; set; }
    int Row { get; set; }
    int Column { get; set; }
}

public interface ICellFactory
{
    ICell Create(int row, int column);
}

public class CellFactory : ICellFactory
{
    public ICell Create(int row, int column)
    {
        return new Cell(row, column);
    }
}
```

and finally, **Board**:

```
public interface IBoard
{
    int Width { get; }
    int Height { get; }

    void Reset();

    // Rest is not important for that question
    // ... 
}

public class Board : IBoard
{
    private ICell[,] cells;
    private readonly ICellFactory cellFactory;

    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        cells = new ICell[Height, Width];
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                cells[i, j] = cellFactory.Create(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    // Rest is not important for that question
    // ...
}
```

**The Question: How can I test Reset method in Board object?** Board is independent from the Game, but it has its own Cells and CellFactory.

Few additional questions related:
 - Is it possible to create Board unit tests? Can I say that, if an object depends on other objects (even if they are interfaces) then it's already has to be integration test, not unit test?

Here is test I made already. (Reset is called in Board constructor):

```
    [Test]
    public void BoardCreationTest()
    {
        var cellFactory = new CellFactory();
        IBoard board = new Board(3, 3, cellFactory);

        for (int i = 0; i < board.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.Width; j++)
            {
                // Check if board.cells[i,j].PlayerId is zero (it has to be zero, player zero is empty cell)
                // Another thing is that cells are private, cause project doesn't need it public
                // Should I make cells public just for tests?

                // Right now I'm checking it IsMoveValid(column, row, playerId)
                // It has to be true, when player 1 wants move in certain cell (it has to be zero, player zero is empty cell)
                Assert.IsTrue(board.IsMoveValid(i, j, 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: **Board constructor:**

```
    public Board(int width, int height, ICellFactory cellFactory)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        this.cellFactory = cellFactory;

        Reset();
    }
```

EDIT2: My whole test now. It passes:

```
[TestFixture]
class BoardTests
{
    private IBoard board;

    [SetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        var cellFact = Substitute.For<ICellFactory>();
        cellFact.Create(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>())
            .Returns(x => new Cell((int)x[0], (int)x[1]));
        board = new Board(3, 3, cellFact);
    }

    [Test]
    public void BoardCreationTest()
    {
        board.Reset();

        for (int i = 0; i < board.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.Width; j++)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(board.IsMoveValid(i, j, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Board can be unit-tested depending on how it get the instance of ICell and ICellFactory. Consider to be able to inject them to allow easier object mocking.

Comment: It is enough that instances of `cellFactory` and `cells` can be injected through constructor. This give you possibility to pass your "testing" implementation of those objects and test `Reset` method behavior.

Comment: @Fabio I inject cellFactory into Board constructor, but what about ICell? I don't inject them cause I have cellFactory - so I create them when I need them. How should I mock cellFactory?

Comment: @mbm I edited my question and added Board constructor. The thing is, it's a factory. Injecting ICell doesn't make sense. I inject ICellFactory and then use it to create cells (9 different cells to be exact, but there could be Board with 10x10, so 100 different cells!!). The question remains, how can I mock Board and CellFacotry so the test will be written using best practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple stub for `CellFactory` and `Cell`, using [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) for example.
In this case you will test only `Reset` method logic

```cs
[Test]
public void BoardCreationTest()
{
    var board = CreateBoard();

    //Calling method explicitly makes test more readable
    board.Reset();

    for (int i = 0; i < board.Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.Width; j++)
        {
           Assert.IsTrue(board.IsMoveValid(i, j, 1));
        }
    }
}

private IBoard CreateBoard()
{
    var cellFactory = Substitute.For<ICellFactory>();
    //You may replace Cell with another mock or smth else. Depends on your assert section.
    cellFactory.Create(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>())
       .Returns(x => new Cell((int)x[0], (int)x[1]));        
    IBoard board = new Board(3, 3, cellFactory);
}
```

`Unit test` mean that you test a single unit of logic. So replacing all dependencies with fakes, gives you ability to test only one unit of logic.

Comment: Just a theoretical question. You're using `.Returns(x => new Cell((int)x[0], (int)x[1])` - what if exception is thrown in Cell constructor?

Comment: @chris You'll get an exception at that line `cells[i, j] = cellFactory.Create(i, j);`

Comment: can you explain me why did you add this line `cellFactory.Create(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(x => new Cell((int)x[0], (int)x[1]))`? It works with this single line: `var cellFactory = Substitute.For<ICellFactory>();` and then `IBoard board = new Board(3, 3, cellFactory);`

Comment: @chris Without this line any call of `cellFactory.Create()` will return `null`.
It's default behavior.